# Update foreign key when updating primary key

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, database-trigger

i have 3 tables :

**table1**

```
A1 primary key
issue
```

**table2**

```
B1 primary key
issue
BA1 references table1 A1
```

**table3**

```
C3 primary key
issue
CB1 references table 2 B1
```

i want to update `TABLE1.A1` and `BA1` auto update
and  the same for `CB1` when updating `TABLE2.B1`

i create a trigger:

this trigger for `TABLE1`

```
 create or replace tigger 1_trg
 after update A1 on TABLE1
  begin
       update TABLE2
       set BA1 := new.A1
       where BA1:= old.A1
   end;/
```

and this one for `TABLE2`

```
 create or replace tigger 2_trg
 after update B1 on TABLE2
  begin
       update TABLE3  
       set CB1:= new.B1
       where CB1:= old.B1
   end;/
```

but it doesnt work because when `1_trg` triggred trigger with him `2_trg`

Comment: Instead of using such a bad formatted table names, u should use something like: Table A,B,C, Column A1,A2,A3.
I got confused after reading your question (because of similar table and column names).

Comment: ...and this is why naming things properly is very important. This is very hard to read and follow. Name them after what the tables/columns/triggers actually contains/are doing instead of trying to shorten it this much.

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik @ Magnus Eriksson  sry for that  i will fix it

Answer (score 1):

If there is no `on update cascade` on Oracle, that is for a good reason.
More info [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5773459616034).

The correct design to handle such a case is to define a separate field as the surrogate key. It must not be a "natural key" (= something that looks unique but eventually change. A good example of natural key, not to be used as primary key, would be the passport number of a person).

Try to update your schema to add 1 primary key column, with numbers generated by an identity for example.
Once this is done, you will have no need for a trigger.

**Edit**: To highlight the discussion below. An important point in the link I have posted is that the use of a trigger for this case can result in undefined behavior.
The type of query that will trigger the undefined behavior is not so common but if that ever happens, it results in a situation that is close to impossible to debug.

Comment: I agree with you, but now I am in the middle of the application if there is any way just help :/

Comment: Well ... my problem with what you want to do goes a bit beyond the design. Tom gives an example of an update trigger and shows it does not work. He's very specific about the case having to be handled **without the use of a trigger**. Read the whole thing again maybe. Do you think you will be able to debug a random behavior like what he described, if it ever happens?

Comment: No i dont think so @lau

Comment: Then if you really need to update a primary key and can't create a surrogate key, I will give you the same advice he's made: 1. change the foreign key to be deferrable (= they will be checked at transaction commit instead of after each statement), 2. handle the update with 2 queries within a transaction, but not with triggers. I do not know how to give you a correct, safe answer with triggers. I believe nobody will know.

Comment: THX for your time i will try to do that while waiting for another idea

Comment: im afraid lau is correct, you need to change your primary key, since its not a real primary key (primary keys shouldnt change ever).